# BAD_CONFIG during CreateContext

Tags: c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am attempting to create a GPGPU program using Open GLESv2.  I've laid out the idea in some demo's I've found and now I'm implementing it.  I am stuck on creating the Rendering Context though.

I do not need to display anything so I create a PixelBuffer Surface and then try to make my context.  However my `eglCreateContext` is throwing `EGL_BAD_CONFIG`.

Could anyone off any advice?  I am attaching my configurations.

**Edit:**  Just tried this on my Windows machine and emulator thinking it may be a VMWare and Software Accelerated OpenGL v2.0 issue.  Same problem though, EGL_BAD_CONFIG.

---

```
EGLint major_ver, minor_ver, num_configs;
EGLint error;
EGLConfig config;


EGLint config_attrib[] =
{
        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_PBUFFER_BIT,
        EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
        EGL_RED_SIZE, 5,
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 6,
        EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 5,
        EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 1,
        EGL_NONE
};
EGLint context_attrib[] =
{
        EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
        EGL_NONE
};

EGLint pb_attrib[] =
{
        EGL_WIDTH, 512,
        EGL_HEIGHT, 512,
        EGL_LARGEST_PBUFFER, EGL_TRUE,
        EGL_NONE
};

eglChooseConfig(ctx->egl_display_, attribute_list, &config, 1, &num_configs)

ctx->pb_surface_ = eglCreatePbufferSurface(ctx->egl_display_, config, pb_attrib);

ctx->egl_context_ = eglCreateContext(ctx->egl_display_, config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, context_attrib);
```

Comment: Hi all, I'm still having trouble with this... am I making a stupid mistake somewhere?  How do I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that even though eglChooseConfig returned `EGL_TRUE` it returned 0 configs... Make sure to check the number of configs returned...